# Update table if value in another table is met

Tags: sql-update, multi-table

I have two tables: one is called **PMWO** and the other table is called **PMWO_DTL**

**PMWO** has a field named **ARCHIVED**

**PMWO_DTL** has a field named **WO_OPEN**

I need to set **ARCHIVED** to **'Y'** when **WO_OPEN** equals **'N'**

the two tables can be linked by the ID's

**PMWO.ID**

and

**PMWO_DTL.PMWO_ID**

Please and thank you.

Bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you can try the below code :

update PMWO set ARCHIVED='Y' where PMWO.ID in (select distinct PMWO_DTL.PMWO_ID from PMWO_DTL where WO_OPEN ='N');

Let me know if it works